# How to initialize SpringWebAplication without dispatcher servlet?

Tags: spring, servlets

I'm using Spring, but not `SpringMVC` in a web applcaition and gotta initialize Spring Application via `web.xml`

I have the standard web-project structure:

```
WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

web.xml is currently contains:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

But my question was caused that any listener should be bound to a servlet. In my case I don't use `dispatcherServlet`. How to load spring `WebApplicationContext`, all spring beans, etc in that case? What do I write in web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ContextLoaderListener` initializes a `WebApplicationContext` and stores it in the `ServletContext` attributes under the name referenced by `WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE`.

You can retrieve it that way.

```
servletContext.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
```

anywhere you have access to the `ServletContext`, after the `ContextLoaderListener` has finished executing.

[As suggested by M.Deinum in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607274/how-to-initialize-springwebaplication-without-dispatcher-servlet/27607315?noredirect=1#comment43640067_27607315), this is such a popular use case that Spring has its own utility to do it:[`WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(ServletContext)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getRequiredWebApplicationContext-javax.servlet.ServletContext-).

You don't need to change anything in your web.xml.

Comment: But we need to bound the context-listener to a servlet, don't we? What servlet the context is bounded to?

Comment: @St.Antario No, you don't. A `ServletContextListener` is a stand alone piece. It can interact with other components through the `ServletContext` attributes.

Comment: Instead of using `servletContext.getAttribute` I would suggest using the `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext`.